# How to apportion HSplit in traitsui-generated window

Tags: python, user-interface, enthought, traits, traitsui

In this [code](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/tutorials/traits_ui_scientific_app.html), there is the following:

```
view = View(HSplit(Item('figure', editor=MPLFigureEditor(),
                        dock='vertical'),
                   Item('panel', style="custom"),
                   show_labels=False,
                  ),
            resizable=True,
            height=0.75, width=0.75,
            handler=MainWindowHandler(),
            buttons=NoButtons)
```

The **HSplit** divides the window into two panels of equal size. What can I do to make one panel take up 1/3 of the space while the other occupies the other 2/3 of the space in the window. I have done a lot of source diving and read the online documentation, but I am not having any luck.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the example here, which you can extend to a split:

EDIT: moved to https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/main/traitsui/examples/demo/Misc/demo_group_size.py

Comment: Moved to https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/main/traitsui/examples/demo/Misc/demo_group_size.py